# Ethical issue about duplicate bridge

Tags: bridge, online

I am returning to bridge after playing online for a few years (covid).  I am an intermediate beginner. I play with a robot (bridge solitaire).  I tried to find a pro bridge player to sit with me while I play the robots and instruct me per hand.  If my choices are good.
They called this unethical.  Please advise.  Thanks

Comment: It's not only unethical, as noted below by [Alexander Woo](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/13579/alexander-woo), but will cripple your bridge. You will just be developing an addictive dependence on the advisor for an activity in which learning how to make non-losing and non-disastrous decisions, independently and in tempo, is one of the most challenging learning curves. If you really want to improve: suck it up.

Answer (score 3):

When you play against the robots, a complete record of your play is kept.  You can look it over afterwards, and ask anyone else to.

It would indeed be unethical to have someone advise you as you are playing.  At that point, you're not playing - your advisor is, and you're falsely claiming the results are yours.  What you can do instead is ask someone to look over your play afterwards and help you figure out what you might have done differently.

Comment: A genuine question: who is being harmed by playing with an advisor, and if the answer is "no human", how is this unethical? I accept that if the OP later goes and states "this is me playing", that is unethical but in that case it is the false claim that is unethical, not the accepting advice in the first place.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I'm assuming play in the context of some competition, even if the competition is for no stakes.

Comment: I'm not convinced that assumption is justified given the information in the question, but agree with you that it is certainly unethical in a competitive scenario. My assumption what that this was purely a learning exercise!

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the circumstances that he playing against robots. In competive play such as tournaments that would be cheating. However in open table- who is he cheating. No should care about open or training table results.